# Iterate JSON data from a base64 encoded text using jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I'd like to iterate through this JSON using jq, but I keep getting an error.

The bash scripting with the jq query I am using is :

```
for row in $(cat output.json | jq -r ' .outConfigs.faultInst[] | @base64'); do
     _ijq() {
      echo ${row} | base64 --decode | jq -r ${1}
      }
     echo $(_ijq '.@cause')
done
```

and the error is:

> jq: error (at :51): Cannot iterate over null (null) exit status
>   5

What am I doing wrong with the jq query, please?

```
{
  "configResolveClass": {
    "@guid": "ddsd2222e2/5d0cce7c-5296-4a2a-b6c3-05bewwewerwewe",
    "@response": "yes",
    "@classId": "faultInst",
    "outConfigs": {
      "faultInst": [
        {
          "@ack": "yes",
          "@cause": "power-problem",
          "@changeSet": "",
          "@code": "F0369",
          "@created": "2019-07-22T15:56:14.616",
          "@descr": "Power supply 1 in fabric interconnect A power: error",
          "@dn": "sys/switch-A/psu-1/fault-F0369",
          "@highestSeverity": "major",
          "@id": "109305",
          "@lastTransition": "2019-07-22T15:56:14.616",
          "@lc": "",
          "@occur": "1",
          "@origSeverity": "major",
          "@prevSeverity": "major",
          "@rule": "equipment-psu-power-supply-problem",
          "@severity": "major",
          "@tags": "network,server",
          "@type": "environmental"
        },
        {
          "@ack": "yes",
          "@cause": "equipment-inoperable",
          "@changeSet": "",
          "@code": "F0374",
          "@created": "2019-07-22T15:56:14.616",
          "@descr": "Power supply 1 in fabric interconnect A operability: inoperable",
          "@dn": "sys/switch-A/psu-1/fault-F0374",
          "@highestSeverity": "major",
          "@id": "109306",
          "@lastTransition": "2019-07-22T15:56:14.616",
          "@lc": "",
          "@occur": "1",
          "@origSeverity": "major",
          "@prevSeverity": "major",
          "@rule": "equipment-psu-inoperable",
          "@severity": "major",
          "@tags": "network,server",
          "@type": "equipment"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you just looking to extract the content of the `@cause` field in the JSON? Why all the roundabouts involving `b64` encode and decode back? The immediate error with your attempt is *not* using the parent field `.configResolveClass` before the `.outConfigs` node.

```
jq -r '.configResolveClass.outConfigs.faultInst[] | ."@cause"' json
```

Extending your attempts with the `base64` encode/decode logic, do

```
ijq() {
    echo "$1" | base64 --decode | jq -r "${2}"
}
```

and your iterate script re-written as

```
while IFS= read -r b64; do
    ijq "$b64" '."@cause"'
done < <(jq -r '.configResolveClass.outConfigs.faultInst[]| @base64' json)
```

For a more robust handling of emitting JSON text with NULL delimit and reading back with a NULL delimit using `-d ''`, you can do

```
while read -d '' -r b64; do
    ijq "$b64" '."@cause"'
done < <(jq -j '.configResolveClass.outConfigs.faultInst[]| @base64| (. + "\u0000")' json)
```

Answer (score 2):

Your sample JSON has "configResolveClass" as the top-level key, so you could use the following as your jq program:

```
.configResolveClass.outConfigs.faultInst[] | @base64
```